# Is it possible for a function of the type $f: P(E) \to P(F)$ not to be surjective?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was wondering if a function of the type $$f: P(E) \to P(F)$$ could not to be surjective.

[image]

In this example, $\forall Y \in P(F), \exists X \in P(E) / f(X) = Y$

because for example, $f^{-1}(\{2\}) = \varnothing$ and $\varnothing \subset P(E)$

Did I make a mistake?

Comment: Is it actually an arbitrary function from $P(E)$ to $P(F)$, or do you have a function from $E$ to $F$ lifted to a function from $P(E)$ to $P(F)$ by mapping sets to their images under $f$? Either way $f$ can easily be non-surjective.

Comment: It's mapping E to F and lifting sets to their images?

Comment: OK. Now are you asking whether the resulting mapping can be surjective? It can clearly be non-surjective, since it will be non-surjective if the underlying $f$ was non-surjective.

Comment: Could you please give me an example of a function of the sort that is not surjective?

Comment: Denote the lift of $f$ by $g$; i.e. $g(A)=\{ f(x) : x \in A \}$. If $x$ is not in the range of $f$, then $\{ x \}$ is not in the range of $g$. Your $f$ in the picture is a perfectly good example.

Comment: Thanks! I understand your example. Still, why is this argument flawed? : Suppose we have $x$ not in the range of $f$. Then, $\{x\}$ is not in the range of $g$. So $g^{-1}(\{x\}) = \varnothing$ and $\varnothing \in P(E)$?

Comment: A function is surjective if its preimages are all non-empty. You also may have missed that $g(g^{-1}(A))$ is a subset of $A$ but in general a *proper* subset of $A$.

Comment: But isn't $\varnothing$ an element of $P(E)$?

Comment: You're sort of making a type error: you're trying to infer that $\emptyset$ (which is indeed in $P(E)$) gets mapped to $\{ x \}$ because $g^{-1}(\{ x \})=\emptyset$. But it doesn't: $g(\emptyset)=\emptyset$. And indeed, this is consistent with the property $g(g^{-1}(A)) \subseteq A$.

Comment: Thank you veryy much. I now understand the contradiction it leads to. However, even if I can demonstrate the constradiction on the paper, I still have trouble imagining it. Isn't it like the preimage of $\varnothing$ is the subset of $E$  $\varnothing$ but that the preimage of an $\{x\}$ not in the range of $g$ is $\varnothing$ which means the inexistence (but not the subset of $E$)?

Comment: For surjectivity, the preimage should *contain* some element of the domain, not *be* an element of the domain.

Answer (score 0):

With your line of argument the set $ f(\phi ) =\{2\}$ but you did not define that as part of your function.

Comment: But isn't it correct that $f^{-1}(\{2\}) = \varnothing$?

Comment: Before speaking of the inverse function you have to have the function well defined. What is $f(\phi)$ for this function ?

Comment: I advanced in my reasoning thanks to @Ian. So let's suppose that $f(\varnothing) = \varnothing$. Then is this statement correct?  : The preimage of ∅ is ∅ (the subset of E) but the preimage of {2} is ∅ which in this case means the inexistence (but not the subset of E)?

Comment: Yes, with this modification, your function is surjective.

Comment: Isn't it not surjective considering that {2} doesn't have any preimage?

Comment: You said the pre-image is empty set.

Comment: I would like to express that {2} doesn't have any preimage. How can I do that mathematically, please? Because I think that saying that $f^{-1}(\{2\}) = \varnothing$ does not express what I want to say.